# Issue at dataSource mat table.How can i solve this issue

Tags: angular

My issue is that table data is not printing and I think my problem is at my dataSource and i have no idea in what way i have to fix it.Ill share my model and related code for the issue.
Here is my model

```
export class HubxModel{ 
    xyz
}
```

and below code is how i define my dataSource

```
 export class UserPatientsReportFormComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['itemTitle', 'itemValue', 'itemUnit'];
    
hubxReportList : Array<HubxDataModel> = [];
```

after console.log(this.hubxReportList)
[image: result]

my database table
[image: database]

Comment: create a stackblitz example. images are not a good presentation for problems.

Comment: i think my issue is at dataSource. Any idea how can i make it right.

Comment: It's looks like the properties of your "array" is not the properties you show, use `console.log(this.huxReportList)` in your subscribe function (I imagine the variables gone in PascalCase instead of CamelCase or similar)

Comment: i have added the result i got after checking console.log(this.huxReportList) please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:(included code example to show only the items of the exact category)**

```
this.usersService
      .getHubxReport(this.clientId)
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response?.data?.length > 0) {
          this.hubxReportList = response.data.reduce((a, i) => {
            if(i.categoryId === theCategoryIdWhichItemsShouldBeShown) {     // <---------------------------- theCategoryIdWhichItemsShouldBeShown property should be replaced with the valid property that you have in your component
               a.push(...(i?.hubxDataItems || []));
            }

            return a;
          }, [] as any);
        }
      });
```

**UPDATE:(included Stackblitz example)**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-design-8ixhfs?file=src/app/app.component.ts

---

Actually, You are using the wrong fields to display in your Template. following your screenshot from **Console**, you don't have `itemTitle`, `itemValue`, and `itemUnit` properties in `hubxReportList` list, you have them inside `hubxDataItems` property of each item, so if you are expecting to show the `hubxDataItems` items in your table you need to modify your component code like as following.

```
getHubxReport() {
    //debugger
    this.usersService.getHubxReport(this.clientId).subscribe((response: ResponseModel) => {
      if (response?.data?.length > 0) {
      this.hubxReportList = response.data.reduce((a, i) => {
         a.push(...(i?.hubxDataItems || []));
         return a;
      }, [] as any)

      }
    }
    );
  }
```

Comment: i have one more question lets say for category = 1 there is a unique itemValue and itemUnit but according to the code that i'm implementing it is printing all the itemValue and itemUnit for all the categoryId. I want to print only the itemtitle,itemvalue and itemunit  according to its categoryId

Comment: so do you mean, you need to show only the first item details  from `hubxDataItems` list for each category?

Comment: for better understanding i have shared my database table. In that table there is categoryId and for every categoryId there is different itemtitle,itemvalue and itemunit data. But at my Mat-table it is printing the itemtitle,itemvalue and itemunit data for all the categoryId . I want to print the data according to its categoryId only

Comment: for now, it shows the whole list of the `hubxDataItems` items for each category, so if you need to show the `hubxDataItems` list of the exact category, then you need to filter the list of `this.hubxReportList`.

Comment: can you give me a stackblitz code for that

Comment: Hello, @ManipuriVlogs I have created the Stackblitz example and updated the answer with the link.

Comment: By the way, please note, that I have included the category Id on the table, you can ignore it, it is just for better understanding.

Comment: thanks alot for the help. I have one question if i want to print the data for only category 1 which part of code i have to change

Comment: let me update the answer with the proper code example

Comment: ok, done, can you please check the updated answer

Comment: please check the link i think its not updated answer is still same

Comment: I have updated an answer, not the Stackblitz example, but I will update it now.

Comment: ok, you can check the example as well

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, in the getHubxReport function you are assigning the result to hubxReportList but you are never assigning this to the dataSource variable.

I think you would need to apply

`this.dataSource.data = response.data;`

alternatively, you can change the table definition in the html file to read:

`<table mat-table [dataSource]="hubxReportList.hubxDataItems" ...`

for it to render properly.

Comment: @ManipuriVlogs according to your updated question, you would need to change [dataSource] = "hubXReportList" to [dataSource]="hubxReportList.hubxDataItems"

Comment: still not working.table shows blank

Comment: @ManipuriVlogs, i would suggest sharing a stackblitz to recreate the problem